# ¿Qué significa '={}' en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, parametros

Tengo el siguiente problema, no sé que significa el siguiente código

`const links = (route, options={})`

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Jamas habia visto una sintaxis asi, pero aparentemente es valida, porque si defines `route` el codigo *NO* da error, sin embargo si imprimes el contenido de links solo te toma como valor un objeto vacio `{}`, que supongo sera el `options`.

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo leer acerca del [Comma operator  (,)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Básicamente, cada `expresión` separada por comas es evaluada (de izquierda a derecha) y retorna la última.

En tu ejemplo:

```
const route = '/something';
let options = { name: 'Jhon' };

const links = (route, options = {});
```

Aquí, primero será evaluada la variable `route`, la cual no es más que una variable, pero la siguiente expresión es **una asignación**, ya que `options` primero tenía asignado un objeto con una propiedad `name` al momento de ser declarado, pero ahora se le asigna un objeto vacío.

Por lo que al final, el último valor es retornado, el cual sería `options` como un objeto vacío. Por ende, la variable `links` será asignada con un objeto vacío.

---

Para entender mejor esto, te pongo una variante de este ejemplo:

```
let options = { name: 'Jhon' };

let route = (options.name = 'Walker');

const links = (route, options)
console.log(links);
```

Aquí `route` ya no es una simple variable y valor, ahora es una expresión compuesta, como sabes, primero será evaluada la primera expresión, la cual es una asignación:

```
options.name = 'Walker'
```

la cual modifica el objeto `options`. Al final, la expresión retornará `options` como:

```
{
    name:"Walker"
}
```

Cada expresión puede ser incluso una función.